# can't load 2 products using load by id method in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, module, php, bundled-product

Friends, I wanna load 2 bundle products using load by id method. this is the code that i have written for that...

```
<?php
$bundled = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$stdid=$bundled->getIdBySku('123457');
$compid=$bundled->getIdBySku('123458');

/*get additional options of the each products*/
 $y=$bundled->load($compid);
 $selectionCollection_complete = $y->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
            $y->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($y), $y);

$x=$bundled->load($stdid);
$selectionCollection_standard = $x->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
            $x->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($x), $x);


 /*store the option head name to an array for future 
  reference*/            
 foreach($selectionCollection_standard as $std_opt)
 {
    $opt_std_hd_names.=$std_opt->getName()."<BR>";
 }
 foreach($selectionCollection_complete as $cmp_opt)
 {
   $opt_cmp_hd_names.=$cmp_opt->getName()."<BR>";
 }


 $display="<pre>".print_r($opt_std_hd_names."<br><br>".$opt_cmp_hd_names)."</pre>"
```

?>

but my problem is $opt_std_hd_names and $opt_cmp_hd_names  returns the same output and they are those options of product which i have loaded first.(in this case $y. if i place the $x code at first, then it displays options of $x).the output is shown below.

```
 output:

   Preparation and Filing of Incorporation Documents
   Verify Business Name Availability
   Unlimited Phone/Email Support
   24/7 Access to Our Online Status Center
   FREE Registered Agent Service for 6 Months
   BizComply (free with your Registered Agent Service)
   500 Four-Color Business Cards
   Business License Application Package
   Palo Alto's Business Plan Pro


   Preparation and Filing of Incorporation Documents
   Verify Business Name Availability
   Unlimited Phone/Email Support
   24/7 Access to Our Online Status Center
   FREE Registered Agent Service for 6 Months
   BizComply (free with your Registered Agent Service)
   500 Four-Color Business Cards
   Business License Application Package
   Palo Alto's Business Plan Pro
```

you can see the outputs are same. why it happens like this?? please give your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the products this way:

```
$y=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($compid);
//and
$x=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($stdid);
```

I have a feeling that using the same instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` (`$bundled` in your case) leads to value being overwritten.

Comment: yes that is correct. I already figured it out. The problem was because i was using the same instance for loading both products. thanks for your valuable reply

Comment: @rajeevktomy mark this as the correct answer then or reply and mark your own answer as correct.